# Inspecting Collections in JetBrains Rider Debugger using Linq functions like Select/Where

Tags: vb.net, debugging, jetbrains-ide, rider, evaluate

I'm debugging a rather large VB.net script in Rider. Several `Dictionary` and `List` objects are constructed and I want to inspect them in the Debugger using Evaluate Expression and query them using Linq functions like `Select` and `Where`.

In JetBrains Rider, setting a breakpoint and opening Evaluate Expression, I can view the objects but when trying to run any function on them, all I get is messages like these:

Expression:
`GroupedProducts.Where(p => p.Key == "1234567").ToList()`

Result:
`'Dictionary<string, string>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary<string, string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Here, the `GroupedProducts` object is of type `Dictionary<string, string>` but the autocomplete suggestions in Evaluate Expression only seem to pickup methods of `Object`.

Is there something I'm missing? I've set JetBrains as the default debugger but that didn't help anything. Any suggestion is welcome.

.Net SDK: .Net Framework v4.7 developer pack
Rider version: 2019.3.1
OS: Windows 10 Professional

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but sometimes the expressions were still evaluated!
Try using `Enumerable.Where(GroupedProducts, predicate)` instead of `GroupedProducts.Where(predicate)` in "Evaluate" window.